# What exactly is a Qualified Domain Name (attention: Not FQDN)?

Tags: domain

So I've searched the net for a definition of QDN but only came across the FQDN definition. But what is the QDN?

Comment: Show some context, where does your "QDN" comes from? You should not trust everything you read on the Internet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you come across this to think that it's a genuine term? I've never seen this acronym used in 15 years.

Fully qualified normally means a full name that contains the hostname and domain, such as `myserver.example.com.`; It can be fully resolved from the root to a single entity in DNS. In that usage I can't see how something could seen be "qualified", but not fully qualified, which may be why I've never seen it used.

FQDN is a bit of a strange acronym though and I remember being confused by it when I was still learning. "Fully qualified hostname" would of made more sense, but even the word "qualified" doesn't really fit based on its dictionary definition.

Comment: Domain Name in FQDN makes more sense than Hostname because the DNS does not store only hostnames but also generic domain names (labels), with different rules.

Comment: I got it from my teacher at school. According to him a QDN is something like <second-level-domain>.<tld>. A FQDN is <hostname>.<second-level-domain>.<tld>.